# Run program that needs root access via PHP

Tags: php, exec

I'm searching to execute a program via PHP, but it needs roots access, because it's accessing hardware stuff.

Is it possible to allow the `www-data` user to execute some programs and access some devices ?

Is it really not safe to add `www-data` in sudo group ?

Comment: Is it not possible to use the SUID bit?

Comment: @Blaatpraat SUID bit is from executables, not device files, is it ?

Comment: true that. That's why I asked, and not directly entered a solution. I'm not the kind of person that would say that you give an user (www-data) more rights, but that would fix the problem immediately (like your post already said). What I can think of is that you create another script (even in PHP is possible), put the SUID bit on that script, and use exec on the PHP script for the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **changing script owner to www-data will make your script executable**.

In Linux, use chown to change script owner

```
chown www-data file.txt
```

This will change file.txt owner to www-data

```
chown -R www-data /files/work
```

Recursively grant ownership of the directory /files/work, and all files and subdirectories, to user www-data.

[Linux chown command details](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm)

In PHP, you can use ***chown*** function to change ownership

```
<?php

// File name and username to use
$file_name= "foo.php";
$path = "/home/sites/php.net/public_html/sandbox/" . $file_name ;
$user_name = "root";

// Set the user
chown($path, $user_name);

// Check the result
$stat = stat($path);
print_r(posix_getpwuid($stat['uid']));

?>
```

[Php chown details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php)

Comment: It's a part of the answer. The real answer should be like `chmod g+rw the device files` and `chown root:www-data the device files`. Then, indeed chown executable or set the group to www-data, just same as the device files.